# Match regex with a date in format yyyy-mm-dd-n

Tags: c#, regex, date

I have this line of code written in C#:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d|\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d)");
```

I want the regex to match any date written in the format yyyy-mm-dd and possibly (if the date already exists in the content) match a format written like yyyy-mm-dd-n, where n is a number between 0-9.

Ex:

2013-02-09 and 
2013-02-09-0

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to match `2013-01-01` or `2013-01-01-0` ? This line `If 2013-01-01-0 exists 2013-01-01 will exist too therefore the date 2013-01-01 already existed.` seems unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you could rewrite your regex in a more simple form: [`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(-\d)?`](http://www.regexr.com/39gml) (click the code to see the regex tester).

I've added some brackets around the date part of the capture group, so it will ignore the trailing `-0`.

What you can do now is:

```
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(richtxbDagensBehandling.Text))
{
    string dateValue = match.Groups[1].Value; //will never contain the -0 part
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this regex that makes the `-\d` optional at the end:

```
\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?:-\d)?\b
```

`\b` is a word boundary
`(?:...)` is a non capture group.